Legend in meta data for land cover / land use codes (e.g. Corine Land Cover) (python)
I am working with Corine Land Cover Data.
Is a legend stored in the meta data or somewhere else which shows the meaning and the official colorcodes of the different land uses?
The product user manual shows the following table:

Would be nice to have this classification already coming with the datafile instead of manually coding it.
I am also interested in other land cover datasets (e.g. ESAworldcover), if they have a legend coming with the datafile.

A symbology used by the landcover map may be embedded into the tif file as a colormap OR as a separate layer file. You can use your GIS to identify if a colormap exists.

The Copernicus Global Land Cover dataset includes metadata files that provide detailed information about the classification scheme and color codes. You can access the full metadata, including a PDF and XML format, on the Copernicus Land Monitoring Service website.
For a comprehensive overview, refer to the "Product User Manual" and the metadata files available for download on the same page. These documents typically include the classification legend and associated color codes.

There is nothing coming directly coming with the .tif file?
